# Why doesn't RequireView() not return a view onResume()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, view, android-view

I'm parsing data with a Volley Request on the onResume() method of my fragment, to populate the layout with the parsed data I need to get the view of my fragment, that's why I'm calling requireView() onResume() after a successfull parsing. 
For the first time now my App crashed on one line which I'm going to mark with a * saying:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DataMain{1a53f20}
>   (4f68cb4d-c05f-4416-932e-26e455fbf106)} did not return a View from
>   onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView().

This is the code:

```
class DataMain : Fragment(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_Data, container, false)
        DataBalance = view.findViewById(R.id.Data_balance)
        // Firebase User Auth
        getUID.requestUidToken()?.addOnSuccessListener { 

                    }?.addOnFailureListener {

                    val unregisteredView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unregistred, container, false)
                    val registerNow = unregisteredView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_registernow)
                    registerNow.setOnClickListener {
                        val mIntent = Intent(activity, LoginMain::class.java)
                        requireActivity().startActivity(mIntent)
                    }
                }
            view
        } else {
            val unregisteredView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unregistred, container, false)
            val registerNow = unregisteredView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_registernow)
            registerNow.setOnClickListener {
                val mIntent = Intent(activity, LoginMain::class.java)
                requireActivity().startActivity(mIntent)
            }
            unregisteredView
        }
    }

        private fun populateDataLayout(res: JSONObject, view: View) {
        val response = Gson().fromJson(res.toString(), ServerResponse::class.java)
        //here I need the view
        val lVDataMenu: ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.lV_DataMenu)
        lVDataMenu.adapter = lVadapter

        else if (response.code == 403) {

        }
}


    override fun onResume() {
        getUID.requestUidToken()?.addOnSuccessListener { getTokenResult ->
            Volley(config.DATA_LOADDATA, { res ->
                **CRASH**populateDataLayout(res,requireView())
            }, {
                tv_unverified.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            })
        }
        super.onResume()
    }
```

I could get rid of the use of "view.findViewById(R.id.lV_DataMenu)" in the populate Routine but then I wouldn't understand the problem here. 
I wasn't able to reacreate the error, so that's why I'm asking. So why is it possible that the requireView() doesn't return a View? Is it because the user switches to the next fragment while Volley isn't finished with the parsing? And how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> override fun onResume() {
>     getUID.requestUidToken()?.addOnSuccessListener { getTokenResult ->
>         Volley(config.DATA_LOADDATA, { res ->
>             **CRASH**populateDataLayout(res,requireView())
>         }, {
>             tv_unverified.visibility = View.VISIBLE
>         })
>     }
> ```

You're not calling `requireView()` in `onResume()` here.

You have two asynchronous calls and you're passing them functions (those lambda expressions in `{}`) as parameters. These functions are invoked later e.g. when the async operation completes. At that time your fragment could have finished its lifecycle.

Two common strategies for handling it:

1. Cancel your pending async calls when the fragment is finishing up. You seem to fire the calls in `onCreateView()` and `onResume()`. The lifecycle counterparts for these would be `onDestroyView()` and `onPause()`. How to do this specifically depends on the async APIs you're using.
2. Fire-and-forget with staleness check: When the async completes, check if the fragment is still alive, otherwise do nothing. For example, change

   ```
   populateDataLayout(res,requireView())
   ```

   to something like

   ```
   view?.let { populateataLayout(res, it) }
   ```

   where `view` is the nullable `getView()` counterpart to nonnull `requireView()`.

Comment: This was very helpfull to understand the problem, thank you sir. May I ask: Is there anything I can read to get deeper into this specific topic and handle the problem with the, as you call it "Fire-and-forget" Method?

Comment: view?.let  = the "let" basically says: if view !=null then {do this here}?

Comment: Yep. The magic is the `?.` safecall operator that invokes the `let` scope function only if the operand is nonnull.